# 'Invalid Next control variable reference' error and can't seem to execute the code?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Ok, this code consists of an array 20 columns across and 1000 rows down, with the four letters A,C,G, and T over and over in different orders. The 20 columns represent people, while the 1000 rows represents DNA base variables. The purpose is to figure out which people are related(i.e. rows 3,6,9), which is determined by having 30 base pair in common, So I am using a search array, 30 rows long, to search, starting with the first 30 in Column 0 and comparing them to the first 30 in column 1, and so on. The code I have below spits out "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference" at the If...Then statement just before the msgbox, "If TempArray (L) = SearchArray(k) then". I am very new at this so I may have other mistakes, but if anyone could help I'd be much obliged. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub FindDNA()

    Dim DataArray(999, 19) As String
    Dim SearchArray(29) As String
    Dim TempArray(29) As String
    Dim StartTime, Elapsed
    StartTime = Timer

    'Load Arrays to be searched, this is loaded into memory for the purposes of speed
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For i = 0 To 19
        For j = 0 To 999

            DataArray(j, i) = Cells(j + 2, i + 2)

        Next j
    Next i
    'Begin search through array to find strings of specified length 30

    For a = 0 To 19
        For b = 0 To 969

            For k = 0 To 29

                SearchArray(k) = DataArray(b + k, a)

            Next k

            'Begin searching of data array for string of ACGT's
            For i = 0 To 19
                For j = 0 To 999

                    For L = 0 To 29
                        TempArray(L) = DataArray(b + L, a + 1)
                    Next L


                    If TempArray(L) = SearchArray(k) Then
                        MsgBox ("Column " & i + 1 & " &  Row " & j + 1)
                    Else
                    End If
                Next b
            Next a

        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the code posted like that, this is the first time I have posted. I apologize if it is confusing.

Comment: You've got your `Next b`, `Next a`, `Next i`, `Next j` in the wrong order... but an easy fix is just to use `Next`... you don't need the `b`, `a`, `i`, and `j`.

Comment: Side note: proper indentation (see this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation)) would help you see the problem

Comment: Oh, I accidentally reported the wrong location for the error. It is actually at Next b

Comment: BigBen, I don't have to add the letters to Next? I just write "Next" four times? Also, which order should they have been in?

Comment: ... And I fixed your indentation, and you should clearly see how the last four `Next` lines are in the wrong order.

Comment: `Next j`, `Next i`, `Next b`, `Next a`... but like I mentioned you can just use `Next`.

Comment: Next j>Next i>Next b> Next a? that order?

Comment: Just drop the last letter and save yourself some hassle :-)

Comment: You posted as I was typing, Thank you! I am very new to this

Comment: " If SearchArray(k) = TempArray(L) Then"---Now I am getting 'subscript out of range' here

Comment: Add a watch to `k` and `L` or `Debug.Print` their values... they're not what you expect :-) They are `30` after their respective loops finish.

Comment: 30 is the size i am wanting the arrays

Comment: `k` and `L` are equal to `30` after the loops finish, not 29 as you might think. Since those arrays have an upper bound of `29`, so you get a `subscript out of range`.

Comment: OH!!! Thank you! I got it worked out and excuted

Comment: Glad to hear, happy to help.